# First MessageBox not showing on FormLoad Event

Tags: vb.net, messagebox, msgbox

In my application I want one of my Windows Form to show a MessageBox if something is true but I am not able to get it but I can solve that by throwing some other event before that MessageBox, I mean it works if some other action is done before that

**My Code for NotWorking MessageBox:**

```
Private Sub MainInterface_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If My.Settings.RowName <> "" Then
            If My.Settings.LastModifiedCheck <> SOMETHING Then
                MsgBox("Hello :)")
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

**My Code for Working MessageBox:**

```
Private Sub MainInterface_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If My.Settings.RowName <> "" Then
        If My.Settings.LastModifiedCheck <> SOMETHING Then
            MsgBox("Hello :)")
            MsgBox("Hello2 :)")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In this code what it will do is, it will show the second `MsgBox`, i.e, `"Hello 2 :)"` but will still ignore the first `MsgBox` which was just `"Hello :)"`

**Edit:**

If I add the style `MsgBoxStyle.Critical` to the MessageBox Style I can hear the Critical Sound but still don't get the MessageBox. No idea what's going on. It seems very bad BTW, I mean this looks impossible! how can a MsgBox closes itself automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, So I solved my problem with this partial solution but still wonder what was the problem...

Instead of adding the `MsgBox` event inside the `Form.Load Event` I inserted the even inside `Form.Shown event`

Example

```
Private Sub MainInterface_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    If My.Settings.RowName <> "" Then
        If My.Settings.LastModifiedCheck <> SOMETHING Then
            MsgBox("Hello :)")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

> And it worked fine!